# Laravel jquery ajax successfully returns data, how to display in view?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a view which uses jquery ajax.  I have successfully returned data back to the view, how do I display the new data in my view?  Here is my code:

```
$( function() {
        $( "#slider-range-ratio" ).slider({
            range: false,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            step: 1,
            value: 50,

            stop: function( event, ui ) {
                var formdata = $("#search_form").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{{ url('search') }}",
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    data: formdata,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(sites){
                        //console.log(sites);
                        $('#search_panel').html(sites);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } );
```

And my view:

```
{{ Form::open(['id' => 'search_form']) }}
<div class="panel-body grey-background" id="search_panel">
                    <input type="hidden" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                            <!-- Start Search Results -->
                            @foreach($sites as $site)
                                @if($site->is_front_page == true)
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-body">

                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">

                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                                            <span class="small pull-left">
                                                                Rank: {{ $site->rank }}
                                                            </span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                                            <a href="{{ url('link/' . $site->url_name) }}">
                                                                <strong class="site-title text-primary pull-right">
                                                                    {{ $site->display_name }}
                                                                </strong>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                 </div>
                                              </div>
                                           </div>
                                        </div>
                                        @endif
                                        @endforeach
                                     </div>
                                  </div>
```

The $sites variable in my view holds an array of objects.  When I check my console the correct sites data is returned back, I want to display the sites data in my foreach loop in the view.

Answer (score 0):

first you should put and `id` for every element that is produced with php :

for exmple:

```
<span class="small pull-left">
    Rank <span id="rank_{{$site->id}}"> {{ $site->rank }} </span>
</span>
```

Then loop trough elements with id = `rank_1`, `rank_2` , ... and fill them with you javaScript value:

```
$("span:regex(class, .*rank_.*)").each(function(item){
     item.html('your value')
})
```